# vue js paginacion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aplicación-web

Estoy tratando de agregar paginador a mi lista en vue js pero no consigo relacionarla al contenido.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    rows: 100,/*campo para paginacion*/
    perPage: 3,/*campo para paginacion*/
    currentPage: 1,/*campo para paginacion*/
    tipoCambio: 0,
    monedaSeleccionada: "",
    monedas: [DOLAR, SOL],
    cuotasDePagoEditado: [],
```

[image: La paginación no aplica al contenido de la lista]

Comment: Por favor incluye todo el codigo de tu componente, incluyendo la template, los metodos, las computed, ect. Imagino que estas usando vue como libreria ya que montas vue directamente sobre el nodo `#app`, aun asi seria util ver como traes y manipulas la data, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo simple de paginación, quizás te puede servir, en vista de que no colocaste código.

```
<li v-for="(user, index) in users" v-show="(pag - 1) * NUM_RESULTS <= index  && pag * NUM_RESULTS > index">
    {{ user.name }} - {{ user.email }}
</li>


<li>
   <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" v-show="pag != 1" @click.prevent="pag -= 1">
      <span aria-hidden="true">Anterior</span>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#" aria-label="Next" v-show="pag * NUM_RESULTS / users.length < 1" @click.prevent="pag += 1">
      <span aria-hidden="true">Siguiente</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

dentro del Vue()

```
data: {
    NUM_RESULTS: 3, // Numero de resultados por página
    pag: 1, // Página inicial
    // JSON a mostrar
    users: [{
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Leanne Graham",
             "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Ervin Howell",
              "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv"
            }]
}
```

Comment: El OP tiene un problema y no le dices como resolverlo.